# pthread scheduling and read()

Tags: pthreads, scheduling

- We are trying to stream raw video from a RAID array.
- With our RAID array it is faster to loop and read 8k at a time than it is to read 8M at once.
- I am trying to modify someone else's multi-threaded C program on openSuse 11.4 linux from (psuedo code)

  ```
  read(fd, buf, 8M)
  ```

  to

  ```
  for(i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
      read(fd, buf, 8K);
  ```
- But the looping version is reading much slower.

My suspicion is that the read thread is being swapped out every time it calls `read()`. I cannot be the first person to have hit this problem, but I've not found any example code for this.  What is the best way to prevent the read thread being swapped out? Change the scheduler/priority? Change thread concurrency?

Comment: Every `read` will be a syscall which is slow. Where did you read that reading 8k in a loop whould be faster?

Comment: I did not read it, I tested. I have used iozone, dd, and a simple program to verify that. Looping reading 8K at a time gives 1.7 GBytes/sec throughput, by the time the read size is increased to 256K one only gets 915 MBytes/sec throughput.

Comment: So to be clear i understand you, the 8k read loop is fast when used in a single threaded program but slow when there are multiple threads?

Comment: A tip is to use for example `strace -e read -T` to see how much time is spent in read syscalls. You could also run with just `-T` and verify that there is no other syscalls that take much time.

Comment: Yes, 8k is fastest in single threaded programs.  In this multi-threaded program (which I will try to fix) larger reads are faster.  I think this is because when the read() blocks the other thread takes over and the read(8k) thread is not awoken until after the other threads time slice is up.  The larger read(32M) is slower for disk throughput, but spends less time "idle" waiting to be re-awoken. Thus I am thinking of changing the scheduler and changing the priority.  But not entirely sure the best way to do this.

Comment: Just about to leave for Xmas, but I will try stracing before I leave.

Comment: Mattias.  I ran strace -c -T -o /tmp/junk for both read(8k) and read(32M).  Output is too long to post here and I am too new to open a chat.  If you e-mail me offline I can e-mail the output to you.

Comment: Upload it to a pastbin so that others can help you too.